# How to source a syntax file from another syntax file in SPSS?

Tags: spss

In R there is the `source` function where you can source an R script from another R script. 
I want to be able to do the same in SPSS.

**How can I source an SPSS syntax file from another SPSS syntax file?**

Answer (score 7):

*Updated Following @AndyW's comments.*

There is the `INSERT` and `INCLUDE` commands. `INSERT` is newer and more versatile than `INCLUDE`.
See documentation on [INSERT here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fsyn_insert_syntax.htm).

The following is the basic syntax template:

```
INSERT  FILE='file specification'
       [SYNTAX = {INTERACTIVE*}]
                 {BATCH       }
       [ERROR = {CONTINUE*}]
                {STOP     }
       [CD = {NO*}]
             {YES}
       [ENCODING = 'encoding specification']
```

Thus, the following command can be placed in an SPSS syntax file

```
INSERT FILE='foo.sps'.
```

and it would import `foo.sps` syntax file.
By default, syntax must follow the rules of interactive mode, and the code wont stop on an error.

To avoid having to specify the full path to the file, the working directory can be specified as an argument in the `INSERT` statement or with a separate `CD` command.
E.g.,

```
CD '/user/jimbo/long/path/to/project'
```

Another option is to use `FILE HANDLE`.

For more information see the SPSS Syntax Reference (available [here as a large PDF file](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/21.0/en/client/Manuals/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_Command_Syntax_Reference.pdf)).

Comment: INCLUDE works, but is limited to batch syntax rules. See the INSERT command, which allows more flexible interactive syntax conventions.

Comment: Also good to note (for long path names) is the FILE HANDLE command which can map a longer path to a shorter name. I like this approach over changing the directory (although both could be used in any situation), because I tend to have more generic scripts and functions I have made in other places than the working directory.

Comment: @AndyW Thanks for the tips; I've updated the answer in light of your comments.