# Chaining SPSS Syntax files

Tags: syntax, spss

iI have a very large (5000 lines) Syntax file and SPSS 19 chokes when I need to modify it.
So I want to split the File into multiple Sub-files. But how to do this? Simply splitting them is risky, because I would have to remember to run every file.
Is there a possibillity to chain several Syntax files so that I can run File A which calls B C D E?
I have read about "include", but it was mentioned that it cannot cope with Identation?

Thank You

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising!
Could you add your comment as Answer?
It is as shame that include is so much more mentioned in the web

Comment: Ok, deleted my comment in lieu of giving it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `INSERT` (and similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149477/604456)). With `INSERT` you don't need to worry about batch syntax rules and indentation, and so you can simply chop up your monstrous syntax file into separate files and use include.

IMO I typically chop up my syntax into separate logical steps for long routines, and I rarely have a syntax file over 400~500 lines long (and most complicated ones are around 100~200). You could always turn off syntax highlighting - but it would still be very hard code to debug and navigate being so huge.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have not wirtten this beast by myself - I recently started working here and my predecessor build this beast.
There are some "wtf?!" moments beside the filesize, e. g. syntax files which must be begun at the top, continued in the end and finished in between...

Comment: Yes @ChristianSauer, I have been there as well. I don't think I have inherited any things that long - but I have certainly inherited code that is largely incomprehensible and un-reproducible without magical insight. Good luck!